# Fedora's firewalld vs iptables

Tags: fedora, firewall, iptables

I am on Fedora 19. Is my understanding correct that as long as `firewalld` is up and running (and properly configured using `firewall-config`) the contents of the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` has no meaning?

I am asking because when I run 'iptables -L' I can see:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

I don't really like this one in particular:

```
"ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere"
```

Comment: Please have a look at our [formatting help](http://superuser.com/editing-help) and indent code or console output by 4 spaces (`Ctrl-K`). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That particular line can be just for the loopback interface. It isn't visible in this output. Try looking into `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` or run `iptables-save` to get the complete configuration including interfaces.

Comment: nn, the only difference between the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` contents and `iptables -L` command is that the command shows you the settings for the `filter` routing table unless you specify explicitly that you want to see the nat, mangle, raw tables...etc if that line were for the loopback that it would contain also `-i lo`

Answer (score 0):

This can be confusing because there is an `iptables` *tool*, an `iptables` *service*, and an `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` *configuration file*.

The `iptables` tool communicates directly with the kernel's packet filter, and this command works whether you are using `service iptables` or `firewalld`.

Based on the documentation [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Security_Guide/sec-Comparison_of_Firewalld_to_system-config-firewall.html), `firewalld` does not use (and presumably ignores) `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. This file normally does not exist on a system configured to use `firewalld`. Instead, `firewalld` uses "various XML files" to permanently save the firewall configuration.

The `ACCEPT all -- anywhere` report from `iptables -L` can be alarming without the `-v` option, which displays the full rule. In this case, the second rule is restricted to the `lo` loopback interface:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
38844   20M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
...
```